# Scrapy and cookie handling

Tags: python-2.7, session-cookies, scrapy

I'm working on learning how to use scrapy. Especially scrapy with cookie handling. The problem is that I can not find a whole lot of examples, tutorials or documentation that can help me in this endeavor. If anyone could supply any material I would be really grateful. To show you how lost I am, the code below should show my lack of understanding;

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar

class sasSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "sas"
allowed_domains = ["sas.no"]
start_urls = []

def parse(self, response):
    Request("http://www.sas.no", meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}, callback = self.nextfunction)

def nextfunction(self, response):
    cookieJar = response.meta.setdefault('cookiejar', CookieJar())
    cookieJar.extract_cookies(response, response.request)

    for cookie in CookieJar:
        open('cookies.html', 'wb').write(cookie)
```

Comment: What isn't working? Scrapy handles cookies automatically.

Comment: @Blender Thank you for looking at my post! I would like to handle cookies manually. The reason is that the site I want to scrape is using javascript to trigger GET requests for cookies that is needed for accessing the page I want to scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually add cookies, just pass them in:

```
yield Request("http://www.sas.no", cookies={
    'foo': 'bar'
}, callback=self.nextfunction)
```

They'll be kept in all future requests. Just remember to do this in the [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) callback if you want them to be there for all of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to attach with a predefined cookies, maybe overwrite `make_requests_from_url` is a better idea:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

  def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    return scrapy.Request(url=url, 
                          cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})
```